# Why this absolute path`import` succeeds from embedded javascript in html file but fails from a dedicated javascript file?

Tags: javascript, browser, module

If I embed javascript code in html file like below then `import` works perfectly fine:

```
  <script type="module">
    import http from 'https://unpkg.com/isomorphic-git@beta/http/web/index.js';
  </script>
```

However, if I move the exact contents from `<script>` tag to a dedicated `main.js` file and include it from html file like below:

```
  <script type="module" src="main.js">
  </script>
```

And make `main.js` file look like this:

```
import http from 'https://unpkg.com/isomorphic-git@beta/http/web/index.js';
```

Then I get following error in Chrome dev console:

> Error in beta/http/web/index.js". Relative references must start with
> either "/", "./", or "../". Failed to resolve module specifier
> "orphic-git@beta/http/web/index.js". Relative references must start
> with either "/", "./", or "../".

I was under impression that embedded JavaScript code can be moved verbatim from html file to a js file and things should just work the same way, but that does not seem to be the case here.

What's going on here?

P.S. if it matters I am using StackBlitz online IDE, but other online IDEs seem to have the same problem. Could it be that webpack or something else messes up the absolute include path?

Comment: The error message seems quite clear to me: you need to use `src="./main.js"`, providing a path that resolves to the URL of your dedicated module.

Comment: @Bergi, no, that is not the problem here. First, it is not complaining about `main.js`, but rather `http/web/index.js` being un-importable. Second, if I remove the `import` line from main.js and replace with `console.log` then console.log works fine even without `src="./main.js"`. So it seems that problem is that import statement behaves different when it is in javascript file or when it is embedded through  <script> tag.

Comment: Ah, right. Can you share the exact contents of your *main.js* file? The error message about "*module specifier `orphic-git@beta/http/web/index.js`*" sounds suspicious - where's the `https://unpkg.com/isom` part of the absolute url?

Comment: @Bergi updated question with main.js contents.